Azure Function running locally but not in Azure
I created a default Azure project in Visual Studio with an HttpTrigger.
This is the only code (its generated by the template).
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}

When I run the code locally it works fine.
Then I do a deploy to an Azure Function (with the publish function in Visual Studio) and when I then run the project I get an error:
27-06-2024, 15:05:54,230
Information
Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=d47ad353-d75f-4ae6-acf7-d560c1d31a73)
27-06-2024, 15:05:54,231

Error
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Everything I try involves some error with a dependancy.
How can I solve this?

are you running in process or out of process mode?


Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The function runtime includes a bunch of assemblies that it uses. These errors are typically caused by the in-process Azure Functions runtime when it tries to remove redundant assemblies.
This behavior causes issues when the assembly version is different than the one which the runtime is using.
To resolve this issue, use _FunctionsSkipCleanOutput mechanism in .csproj which helps to skip removing redundant packages as part of its clean out process, refer the article.
<PropertyGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>


Use the latest version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions dependency in the Azure function:

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Code Snippet:
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
        : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}


Deployed the function to Azure function app.

Portal:



I created a new project and did exactly what you said. But still it doesn't work. Also there is no function.json like in your screen. Im using .net 8.

Your code looks like In-process code. .NET 8 isolated function code should be like the code shown in the image.

I think you're right. I've created a .NET 6 project, upgraded that to .NET 8 and the whole project looks different than when creating a new .NET 8 project from the Create Project Window. When I update from .NET 6 to .NET 8 everything works, also when deployed to Azure.
